# Profiling Neo4j path query

Tags: neo4j, profiling, cypher

I want to know how a path query has been executed in neo4j. For example, I have a path query shown below:

```
match p=(n)-[r*1..10]->(m)
where
  (
    n.URI='http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Jacob_T._Schwartz' OR
    n.URI='http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Anna_Karina'
  ) AND
  filter(x IN r where type(x)=~'.*hasAcademicAdvisor.*') AND
  filter(y IN r where type(y)=~'.*isCitizenOf.*') AND
  filter(z IN r where type(z)=~'.*participatedIn.*') AND
  filter(u IN r where type(u)=~'.*happendedIn.*') AND
  filter(v IN r where type(v)=~'.*dealsWith.*')
return p, length(p) order by length(p) desc;
```

This query is to find paths in a graph database with source node "http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Jacob_T._Schwartz" or "http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Anna_Karina" that have certain relationships.

I used the PROFILE command with this query and below is the execution plan I got.

[image]

Note that the content in row 5 col 5 is too long, so I put *** instead of putting the actual content.

Actually, *** denotes `((((((Property(n,URI(0)) == {  AUTOSTRING0} OR Property(n,URI(0)) == {  AUTOSTRING1}) AND nonEmpty(FilterFunction(r,x,RelationshipTypeFunction(x) ~= /{  AUTOSTRING2}/))) AND nonEmpty(FilterFunction(r,y,RelationshipTypeFunction(y) ~= /{  AUTOSTRING3}/))) AND nonEmpty(FilterFunction(r,z,RelationshipTypeFunction(z) ~= /{  AUTOSTRING4}/))) AND nonEmpty(FilterFunction(r,u,RelationshipTypeFunction(u) ~= /{  AUTOSTRING5}/))) AND nonEmpty(FilterFunction(r,v,RelationshipTypeFunction(v) ~= /{  AUTOSTRING6}/)))`

Sorry for bad format.

Can anybody help me explain the plan? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you look at the plan from the text console that you read it from bottom to top.  This you can see that it is first finding every single path between `n` every other node `m` which is of length 1-10 (which is obviously a lot).  After it has found all of those paths, then it takes them and chooses which ones to keep with the filter.

If you can, you should try putting relationship conditions on the path match rather than in a filter so that Neo4j can filter as it's traversing and stop traversing if it doesn't match, which can save you a lot of DB accesses.  I notice that your relationship type matching is pretty loose, so I don't know how hard that would be, but if you know all of the possible relationship types then you should specify them like this:

```
match p=(n)-[r:hasAcademicAdvisor|isCitizenOf|participatedIn|happendedIn|*1..10]->(m)
```

I'd be curious for more info on why your using a regex to match the relationship types.  I know sometimes people put dynamic values in for their relationship types (like an ID), and that's generally a code smell, in my experience.  Often you can instead use a relationship property.

A couple of other notes: You're not using labels, so in order to find nodes with the `URI` property that you've specified it will first need to search the entire database.  If you use a label and create an index or a constraint on `:Label(URI)` then that part will be much faster.

I would also use `IN` to match the `URI` in this case:

```
WHERE n.URI IN ('http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Jacob_T._Schwartz', 'http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Anna_Karina')
```

Lastly, you should also be able to take advantage of regular expressions to make this simpler (and perhaps more efficient):

```
filter(x IN r where type(x)=~'.*(hasAcademicAdvisor|isCitizenOf|participatedIn|happendedIn|dealsWith).*') AND
```

But again, that's not as efficient as putting it into your `MATCH` if that's possible.

Comment: Thank you so much, Brian. Yes, I do have my reasons using a regex to match the relationship types. Actually, in my application scenario, I want to find paths between a set of nodes such that these paths contain all the specified relationships. However, I don't care about the order of the relationships. This is the only way I figured out to be able to achieve my goal. Also, I agreed with you about adding label and using index for performance. I will try that!

Comment: FWIW, the syntax that I gave doesn't specify a specific order, only that all relationships along the path must be one of the specified types

Comment: However, I need all of them to be appeared in the final paths.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, hence the `AND`s.  It still might help to reduce your search space if you put it into the `MATCH`.  Also using the `ANY` function would likely be faster than `FILTER` because it can stop once it's found an answer.

Comment: But for your usecase of making sure that all relationships exist along the path you may want to investigate unmanaged extensions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will take a look at unmanaged extensions to see if it will help here.

Comment: also instead of filter consider the ALL or ANY predicates

Comment: you can post-check the rel-types after you used them in the match with 
`WITH ['hasAcademicAdvisor', ...] as types MATCH ... AND ALL(type in [r in rels | type(r)] WHERE type IN types)`

Answer (score 0):

- **Use labels,**
- Use Neo4j 2.3.x,
- Use a constraint on :Resource(URI)
- Considering removing the URI prefix from your URI values, it is just waste in the DB, or replace with a namespace on import
- don't use regexps for rel-type matching, you can use sensible rel-types to begin with
- remove ambiguity from your relationship-types

Try this for your query (after fixing the URIs and rel-types)

```
match p=(n:Resource)-[:hasAcademicAdvisor|:isCitizenOf|:participatedIn|:happendedIn|:dealsWith*1..10]->(m:Resource)
where n.URI IN ['Jacob_T._Schwartz', 'Anna_Karina']
return p, length(p) 
order by length(p) desc;
```

For query plan details see the extensive docs in the Neo4j manual

- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-tuning.html
- http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/execution-plans.html

Also consider Neo4j browser for a more visual query plan

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael. I will try what you suggested.